# worst Fit SLOB allocator algorithm

Tags: unix

I have been looking the whole internet for the algorithm of worst-fit, but What I found was best-fit and first-fit.

Is there any possible chance to get worst-fit algorithm?

My Operating System project says that I have to compare the first-fit,best-fit and worst-fit of SLOB allocator. But as far as I know SLOB allocator is replaced with SLAB allocator.

Comment: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_worst_fit_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The worst-fit is simply the largest block available, given that the block is larger than the requested size (if no block is larger than the requested size, it returns nothing).